# C++ Why isn't my vector of objects printing the objects' variables?

Tags: c++, object, vector, cout

I'm filling `std::vector<Box> boxes` with 9 `Box` objects, each with their own string variable `name`. Just as an error check, I'm trying to go through the vector of objects and print each object's `name` variable. However, the console remains blank. Here's the function that fills and prints the vector:

```
void Engine::FillVector(){
Board board;
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    Box box;
    board.GetBoxes().push_back(box);
    }
int size = board.GetBoxes().size();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    board.GetBoxes()[i].SetName("box");
    std::cout << board.GetBoxes()[i].GetName();
    }
}
```

So "box" should be displayed nine times in the console right? `GetBoxes` simply returns the vector `boxes`, and `SetName` also simply sets each `Box` object's name to `"box"`. Why does the console remain blank?

Comment: What does `Board::GetBoxes()` look like?

Comment: I bet two leek slices that `GetBoxes` returns by value.

Comment: `std::vector<Box> Board::GetBoxes(){return boxes;
}`

Comment: Return a reference (or a pointer), otherwise your modifications won't appear in 'boxes'.

Comment: Leek slices this way, thanks.

Comment: I'm rusty on references/pointers. Can I get an example for this problem? And @Quentin: [link](http://www.leekspin.com)

Comment: You just defined Box box; without allocating it memory. You need to allocate your variable box memory: simply, box = new Box(); this will create an object instance of the class Box.

Comment: Your board.GetBoxes() function, should return a pointer to your vector. However we do not know if you used a pointer as an array of your data structure. Usually, to make a references to the Box instance in a vector, you need to use ".at(i)" function and maybe something like board.GetBoxes().at(i); It appears, however that you are using an array index to make a reference to objects inside a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<Box> Board::GetBoxes(){return boxes; }
```

This returns a copy of your `boxes` every time you call it.

```
std::vector<Box> &Board::GetBoxes(){return boxes; }
//               ^ Hi!
```

This returns a *reference* to your vector. You can then act on it from the outside at will.

It's often best complemented with a const overload :

```
std::vector<Box> const &Board::GetBoxes() const {return boxes; }
```

...for read-only access.

For more information about references, I will shamelessly link you to [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827592/what-is-definition-of-reference-type/24827998#24827998).