# What does "owning" mean in the context of programming?

Tags: c++, string-view

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) uses it to describe
std::string_view:

> - [`std::basic_string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) (C++17) - a
>   lightweight **non-owning** read-only view into a subsequence of a string.

[devtut](https://devtut.github.io/cpp/std-string.html#using-the-std-string-view-class)
and
[sodocumentation](https://sodocumentation.net/cplusplus/topic/488/std--string#using-the-std--string-view-class)
use it to describe std::string_view as well:

> C++17 introduces `std::string_view`, which is simply a **non-owning** range of
> `const char`s, implementable as either a pair of pointers or a pointer and a
> length.

And [various other questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%22owning%22) here on SO
reference it, yet I can't find any explanation of what it means.

Comment: Owning an object means having the responsibility of deleting it, that is calling its destructor. In the case of shared_ptr, which implies multiple owners, its the responsibility of the owners to make sure the last to own the object deletes it.

Comment: In this context owning means to be responsible for the memory management, especially for freeing allocated memory.

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `c++ ownership` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%2B%2B+ownership)? Or [`c++ what is ownership`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%2B%2B+what+is+ownership)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is ownership of resources or pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers) I found it as the second result from that second query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can own a resource, i.e. anything that there is a limited amount of. This is usually memory or system handles. Whatever owns the resource is responsible for releasing it when done using it.

`std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` are examples of an *owning* wrapper. It releases their memory when it goes out of use. Same goes for any other [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) class.

`std::basic_string_view` is *non-owning*, which is a nice way of saying that it is not bound to actual lifetime of the string in any way, and that, if you are not careful, it may dangle if the string reallocates.

Answer (score 2):

"Owning X" means being responsible for the lifecycle of X.

In case of a `std::string` the class contains an array of `char`. The `std::string` class is responsible for allocating and deallocating the char array; the whole time the string object owns this array.

In contrast to this `std::string_view` only "knows about" such an array; It doesn't do any allocations or deallocations with it.

The benefit is that you don't need to do a copy of the array which could get expensive, the drawback is that if you aren't careful, the array could be freed before you stop using the `std::string_view` which results in undefined behavior so the result could be your program crashing.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes That's why I wrote "could crash"; clarified it a bit in the answer...

Answer (score 2):

[An answer to a question about std::span](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45723820/15869059) says:

> A `span<T>` is:
>
> ...
>
> - A non-owning type (i.e. a
>   ["reference-type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827592/what-is-definition-of-reference-type)
>   rather than a "value type"): It never allocates nor deallocates anything and
>   does not keep smart pointers alive.

The linked answer provides a good explanation of what a reference *type* is.

std::string_view and std::span are objects with reference *semantics*. [isocpp's faq](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/value-vs-ref-semantics) provides a good explanation.

Comment: The link talks a lot about C++ references as a type, I'd suggest mentioning [objects with reference semantics](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/value-vs-ref-semantics), which is what `string_view` and `span` are