# To slice or not to slice when passing inheriting reference types

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, object-slicing

I'm working on some code involving "real-life" as opposed to program-only entities. Let's say that it's a camel-handling library. Now, my library has two camel [reference-type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24827592/1593077) classes: `Camel` and `SingingCamel`. `Camel` is a concrete class with no virtual members; and `SingingCamel : public Camel { }` is a camel which can sing, and programming-wise, has no overrides/shadowing. There is no problem treating a singing camel like a non-singing one.

Now, since these are both reference-type rather than value-type classes, I would rather pass them around by value. Unfortunately, if I write:

```
void have_joyride(Camel camel, Person person)
```

(remember - these are *reference* classes; this does not create a new camel or new person)

... then I am slicing my `SingingCamel`.

The C++ core guidelines [say](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-slice):

> **ES.63: Don't slice**
>
> Slicing -- that is, copying only part of an object using assignment or initialization -- most often leads to errors because the object was meant to be considered as a whole. In the rare cases where the slicing was deliberate the code can be surprising.

Now, it's not that I can't avoid slicing. I could certainly write:

```
void have_joyride(Camel const &  camel, Person const &  person);
```

and that would work fine. ... except that, in this case, I would actually need to have *four* functions:

```
void have_joyride(Camel const &  camel, Person const &  person);
void have_joyride(Camel const &  camel, Person       && person);
void have_joyride(Camel       && camel, Person const &  person);
void have_joyride(Camel       && camel, Person       && person);
```

and this violates [another](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-DRY) C++ core guideline:

> **ES.3: Don't repeat yourself, avoid redundant code**
>
> Duplicated or otherwise redundant code obscures intent, makes it harder to understand the logic, and makes maintenance harder, among other problems. It often arises from cut-and-paste programming.

as well as [this one](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-in):

> **F.16: For "in" parameters, pass cheaply-copied types by value and others by reference to const**
>
> Both let the caller know that a function will not modify the argument, and both allow initialization by rvalues.

And so I ask myself:

To slice, or not to slice, that is the question:
Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
The lrefs and rrefs of outrageous overloads,
Or to take values from inheriting reference objects,
And by passing, slice them.

Notes:

- No camels were sliced during the writing of this question!
- Related, more general treatment: [Where should I prefer pass-by-reference or pass-by-value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4986341/1593077)

Comment: Why not `template <typename Camel, typename Rider> void have_joyride(Camel camel, Rider person);` or `template <typename Camel, typename Rider> void have_joyride(Camel&& camel, Rider&& person);`?

Comment: @NathanOliver: 1. Because it's an obfuscation, which also suggests that other classes may be passed into `have_joyride()`. And if I wanted to limit it, I'd need to write a requirement, and either make it uglier with SFINAE or introduce a concept and depend on C++20. 2. Because F.16.  ...  Still, that could be an answer.

Comment: Why do you need those overloads?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reference class"?

Comment: @NathanPierson: See edit.

Comment: @Jarod42: Because in my great desert kingdom, we sometimes get rvalue camels...

Answer (score 2):

This is what the C++ core guidelines [say](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#alternative-8) you could do:

> Alternative
>
> If you mean to slice, define an explicit operation to do so. This saves readers from confusion.

And adapting their example, I would get:

```c++
class SingingCamel : public Camel {
    public:
    Camel as_camel();
    // ...
};

SingingCamel sc { /* ... */ };
Camel c1 {sc};  // ideally prevented by the definition of Camel
Camel c2 {sc.as_camel()};
```

But frankly, I don't like this solution that much. I want to pass my `SingingCamel` to functions which take `Camel`s, naively and in a straightforward manner.