# allocate null vector by reference

Tags: c++

How can I allocate a vector by reference? The issue is that the pointer in the foo function does not return by reference as being allocated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>



void foo(std::vector<std::string>*ss) {
    if (ss == nullptr) {
        ss = new std::vector<std::string>();
    }
}

void add(std::vector<std::string> *ss) {
    ss->push_back("test");
    ss->push_back("test1");
    ss->push_back("test2");
    ss->push_back("test3");
    ss->push_back("test4");
}

int main(void) {
    std::vector<std::string> *ss = nullptr;

    foo(ss); //Does not get new vector
    add(ss); //seg fault because still nullptr 
    for (auto i : *ss) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
    ss->clear();
    delete ss; ss = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void foo(std::vector<std::string>*&ss) {`

Comment: Ohhhhhh. Wait. Can you explain why that works? It's a  * (pointer) of a & (address) so you can pass it a pointer? To me that is weird since I normally don't do it like this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In what way is this question "not reproducible" or "caused by a typo"? Please try and use appropriate close reasons. Especially when the question is an obvious dupe, and you can use your hammer single-handedly.

Comment: @boardkeystown Many symbols in c++ have multiple meanings, which depends on the context. In `std::vector<std::string>*&ss` the `&` symbol is not the "address of" operator. It indicates a reference type. See [What is definition of reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827592/what-is-definition-of-reference-type).

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>*&ss` does not specify a pointer of an address.   It's a reference to a pointer.